# CSS not working in firefox (or HTML displayed as simple text)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

This is a simple webpage which compares two photographs and changes the one which is not clicked. The code is perfectly working in Chrome but in Firefox, HTML is being displayed as simple text and even links are not working.
**CODE:-**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
header {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Magneto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px grey;
  -ms-box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px grey;
  -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px grey;
  -o-box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px grey;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 7px grey;
}
main {
  margin: 10px;
}
#ques {
  font-family: Cooper;
  font-size: 125%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#imageContainer {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.image {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
}
#or {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
}
#leftImage {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#rightImage {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .image {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
aside {
  font-size: 105%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:/staticFbs.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#leftImage").click(function() {
        x = x + 2;
        $("#rightImage").attr("src", "D:/staticFbp/boys/" + (x) + ".jpg");
        if (x > y) {
          var temp = y;
          y = x;
          x = temp;
        };
      });
      $("#rightImage").click(function() {
        y = y + 1;
        $("#leftImage").attr("src", "D:/staticFbp/boys/" + (y) + ".jpg");
        if (x > y) {
          var temp = y;
          y = x;
          x = temp;
        };
        if (y > (x + 1)) {
          x = x + 1;
        };
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1><abbr title="Ranking fun">SJSBook</abbr></h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h3 id="ques">Q: Who is better?</h3>
    <div id="imageContainer">
      <img src="D:/staticFbp/boys/1.jpg" alt="Contestant 1" class="image" id="leftImage" />
      <div id="or"><b>OR</b>
      </div>
      <img src="D:/staticFbp/boys/2.jpg" alt="Contestant 2" class="image" id="rightImage" />
    </div>
    <aside><em>Feel free as your votes will be confidential.</em>
    </aside>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

[Preview of webpage in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fHXy.png)

Comment: check You css link Href path ..

Comment: works here, what is your extension file ? is it html or some other extension name (folder/server not the same :) )

Comment: css link href is correct (checked it and as its working in chrome too) @hemanjosko

Comment: HTML file's extension is .html. I double checked it, every element's path is correct @GCyrillus

Comment: @ChaitanyaBhardwaj i just execute your code on my machine its working download source here - [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8auSwhRkiUzYTZPNGhNNnN3Ukk) only i dont have images that you are using. and even its working on firefox also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative path not absolute Paths :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="staticFbs.css" />
```

Comment: Though that path indeed looks funny I see no reason why it should not work. Apart from that this would not explain why the html markup is shown as text instead.

Comment: Apply this to the image paths as well

Comment: What's your HTML file extension ?

Comment: All paths used are correct indeed casue the webpage is working right in chrome. While in firefox CSS, links and not even javascript is working. HTML file extension - .html @arkascha

Comment: Using relative path actually solved the problem and now firefox is displaying it correctly. Thanks for help.

Comment: Good news !  Firefox seems to have a problem with absolute drive paths.

Comment: This is not generally the case, I just check for two different systems. Appears to be a FF @ MS-Windows specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link that from your project. Put the CSS files to your project under root folder or whatever.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../foldername/staticFbs.css" />
```

Comment: I've added a link to webpage view in firefox.

Comment: try to use **<head>** section

Comment: It's actually working after I used relative links instead of absolute links.

Answer (score 0):

You are linking to your D-drive, in both your CSS-filepath and also in your jQuery.. This won't work when you put it online, so if you fix it on local, chances are it will also fix your Firefox-issue.